# Deskewing indivisual characters in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, text-extraction

I'm trying to defeat an anti-bot feature in a program where a user has to click on letters within a image in alpha-numerical order. I have managed to somewhat extract the text from the background using preprocessing, but still need to deskew each indivisual character to get optimal results using Tesseract.

Image before using Hough Lines, just preprocessing
[image]

Original images with lines detected by HoughLinesP drawn
[image]
I have tried to use Canny Edge Detector + Hough Lines to try and find the line below each character. However, it deemed inconsistent and too reliant on the quality of the line, and I can't differentiate the bottom line and lines detected on the characters itself.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import cv2, numpy as np, time
img_roi = [48, 191, 980, 656]  # x1, y1, x2, y2
src_img_dir = "images/source/9.png"
bg_img = cv2.imread("images/background.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)[img_roi[1]:img_roi[3], img_roi[0]:img_roi[2]]
# The background of the area is constant. So I have used a reference background image and removed pixels which have a similar H value as the background

bg_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(bg_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
src_img = cv2.imread(src_img_dir, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)[img_roi[1]:img_roi[3], img_roi[0]:img_roi[2]]
# This image is the image where letters are placed on top of the background image

src_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(src_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = np.zeros([src_img.shape[0], src_img.shape[1], 3], dtype=np.uint8)

offset = 3
start_time = time.time()
for y in range(src_img.shape[0]):
    for x in range(src_img.shape[1]):
        sp = src_hsv[y][x]
        bp = bg_hsv[y][x]

        if bp[0]-offset <= sp[0] <= bp[0]+offset:
            if sp[1] >= 109:
                mask[y][x] = src_img[y][x]
        elif sp[1] <= 90:
            if sp[0] >= 67:
                mask[y][x] = src_img[y][x]
            elif sp[2] >= 125 and sp[1] >= 20:
                mask[y][x] = src_img[y][x]
        else:
            mask[y][x] = src_img[y][x]
        """if sp[1] >= 60 and sp[2] >= 60:
            mask[y][x] = src_img[y][x]
            #mask[y][x] = conv"""

print("duration", time.time()-start_time)
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
#mask[:,:,2] = 255
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
mask_gray = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(mask_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
opened = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, (3,3))
opened = cv2.morphologyEx(opened, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, (3,3))
opened = cv2.erode(opened, (3,3))
opened = cv2.dilate(opened, (3,3))
opened = cv2.dilate(opened, (5, 5))
opened = cv2.morphologyEx(opened, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, (3,3))
opened = cv2.erode(opened, (3,3))
opened = cv2.erode(opened, (3,3))
final_img = opened
#edges = cv2.Canny(final_img, 0, 255)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(final_img, 1, np.pi / 180, 20, minLineLength=10, maxLineGap=3)
for line in lines:
        coords = line[0]
        cv2.line(src_img, (coords[0], coords[1]), (coords[2], coords[3]), [255,255,255], 2)
#cv2.imshow("can", edges)


#cv2.drawContours(src_img, fixed_contours, -1, (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.imshow("src", src_img)
cv2.imshow("", final_img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From first glance, it appears the skew is not very strong, and the characters are far apart.

I'd do a multi-step approach on your filtered image (pretty good already)

- first detect areas of interest that contain two significantly large blobs (letter/numeral + underline), filtering out noise pixels
- then detect the underline explicitly as being the long and flat of the two (letter 'I' and numeral '1' could be problematic in this regard)
- use underline orientation in relation to local area of interest (underline + character) to determine which side is down
- determine angle of skew heuristically: assuming x degrees (loop over narrow range of x), how much signal of local area of interest is inside quadrilateral above underline, such that angle between bottom (underline) and left is x.
- use image-unwarp function such that underline is mapped to bottom edge of a rectangle of appropriate width to height ratio
- profit

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually was able to extract the indivisual characters and deskew the text. However, if you take a closer look at the letters, especially the number 7 on the image I linked above, parts of the letter is "shifted", effectively deforming the letter, and running Tesseract with default english training data, it was having a hard time detecting such deformed characters. Do you think the letter can be aligned correctly?

Comment: You could dilate the binarized letters. Increasing line width that way could probably fix that problem.

Comment: I've attemoted Dialation, but one problem I had was for some letters like "1" or "L" which has a horizontal line on bottom, the line would actually get merged with the baseline. I've tried reducing the kernel size, but sincne the image is quite small(around 60 by 60 pixels), changing kernel size just by 2 makes a large difference. If I were to rescale the image to something like twice the original size, can the Dialation kernel be fine tuned?

Comment: You can check out some letter outputs here: https://imgur.com/a/ZfILkNf

Comment: Once you have identified the bottom line blob, you can remove just that blob from your image (or your unwarped rectangular image) and THEN dilate the rest. That way, the character should not get stuck to the bottom line.